# Using modelview matrix to get global coordinates

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

Suppose I have a local coordinate and I want to get the global coordinate.  In order to do so I call gltranslatef(...) and glrotatef(..).  I want to multiply the current matrix by the local coordinate to get the global coordinates.  Is it possible to extract the global coordinates in this manner?

Comment: Sorry, you want to do what? glTranslate and glRotate merely manipulate the matrix on top of the active matrix stack. You want to transform some vector with that matrix?

Comment: Yes, that vector will have the x y and z value of the coordinate

Comment: Well, like you already assumed: Matrix multiplication. I think those pages are of interest for you: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Transformation and http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Viewing_and_Transformations – also keep in mind that the fixed function matrix stack (glMatrixMode, glTranslate, glRotate, glScale, glPushMatrix, glPopMatrix) has been deprecated and even removed from later versions of OpenGL.

Comment: Try to skip using the fixed functions for manipulating the modelview matrix and use GLM. A good way to learn.